# como usar o .on e .off no jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou querendo saber como faço para usar de maneira correta o .on e o .off por exemplo se eu clicar em algum elemento ou então mandar ele fazer um fadeIn quando clicar em .on e depois desativar ele com .off clicando em outro elemento por exemplo

Comment: procura por jquery toggle

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, não dá pra entender exatamente o objetivo que você quer atingir. Se pudesse deixar a pergunta mais clara, ficaria mais fácil para ajudarmos.